# UIScrollView inside a UITableViewCell - No didSelect call

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I have a `tableviewCell`, where the user can `scroll` horizontally. Since the `scrollView` covers nearly the whole `cell`, the `tableView` method `didSelectRow` gets not called if the user clicks the `cell`.

So I thought, I could pass the touch event of the `UIScrollView` to the `cell`, but still the `didSelectRow` doesnt gets called.
I subclassed `UIScrollView` to pass the touch event only, if the touch was not a drag:

```
- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
{
    NSLog(@"touch scroll");
    // If not dragging, send event to next responder
    if (!self.dragging)
        [self.superview touchesEnded: touches withEvent:event];
    else
        [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
}
```

Any ideas on how to pass the click to the table, to get the delegate-methods called and keep the scrolling inside the `scrollview`?

Comment: try setting userInteraction of scroll view enabled.

Comment: Since the scrolling works fine, the userInteractions is already enabled.

Comment: Well Then shorten your scrollView set AccerrraryButton to detail disclosure, and perform your desired task of didSelect here.

Comment: Perhaps you need to call `[super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event]` all the time rather than in the second branch of your else?

Answer (score 22):

You can actually do this without subclassing `UIScrollView`.  Whether you have a custom cell, or are setting properties in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in the `UITableView`, you can do the following:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:yourScrollView];
yourScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[cell.contentView addGestureRecognizer:yourScrollView.panGestureRecognizer];
```

The reason you can do this is because scrollView has its own panGestureRecognizer that's accessible to the programmer.  So, just adding it to the cell's view will trigger the scrollview's gesture delegates.

The only drawback of this approach is that subviews of the scroll view are unable to receive any touch input. If you need this you will have to chose a different approach.

Answer (score 7):

I just encountered the same problem. 
In your subclass make sure to include the full set of methods:

```
-(void) touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (!self.dragging)
        [self.superview touchesCancelled: touches withEvent:event];
    else
        [super touchesCancelled: touches withEvent: event];
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (!self.dragging)
        [self.superview touchesMoved: touches withEvent:event];
    else
        [super touchesMoved: touches withEvent: event];
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (!self.dragging)
        [self.superview touchesBegan: touches withEvent:event];
    else
        [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (!self.dragging)
        [self.superview touchesEnded: touches withEvent:event];
    else
        [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer is correct, but I updated the code based on a bug I was getting.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (self.dragging) {
        [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    } else {
        if ([self.delegate isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            [(UITableViewCell *)self.delegate touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
        }

        [self.superview touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

If your `self.delegate` is not the `UITableViewCell`, than replace that property with a property to your cell.

The cell needs to retrieve the cancel touch event during movement to prevent the undesired results. It can be easily reproducible as follows.

- Highlight the cell (assuming the scroll view is over the whole cell, if not highlight the scroll view)
- While the cell is highlighted, drag the table view
- Select any other cell and now the previously highlighted cell will retrieve the `didSelectCell` state

Another point to mention is that order matters! If the `self.delegate` is not called before the `self.superview` then the highlighted state wont happen.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

```
scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
contentView.addGestureRecognizer(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer)
```

Answer (score -1):

try set this

```
_scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO
```

also, it is bad to partially forward touch events