# Custom UITableViewCell: programmatically trigger selection segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a custom UITableViewCell containing a UIScrollView. Unfortunately, the scroll view intercepts taps, so I added my own tap gesture recognizer.

Now when a user taps on my custom cell I'd like to trigger the selection segue that I configured in Interface Builder, but I can't figure out how to access the target and action from my custom UITableViewCell subclass that I set in IB. How would I do that?

PS: I'm aware that I could use a custom scrollview as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15364707/901334 However, that doesn't seem as clean to me as simply triggering the action configured in Interface Builder in my custom cell.

Answer (score 5):

Try to remove the "selection segue" and create a push segue from controller to controller and perform it on

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PUSHSEGUE" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: That would work, but I'm interested in learning how I can access the configured target/action in my custom UITableViewCell subclass. editAction is deprecated, there must be something else...